# Awaiting AE recommendation before "acceptance or rejection"

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, thesis, peer-review

**Is** it ok to ask the journal about the status of my manuscript or it will affect their decision about it?

Comment: What information do you hope to gain? Until the editor makes their recommendation there is no news to give you.

Comment: You never rush an editor or reviewers.  They are volunteers.  I know of an editor who only reads his/her email and perform his/his editor duties once a month.   So any emails until then are ignored!